# Gedit as the default editor in crontab

Tags: command-line, cron, gedit, default-programs, editor

How do I make gedit the default editor for crontab?

So far I've tried:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor gnome-text-editor /usr/bin/gedit 100
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/gedit 100
```

No luck so far. (maybe I just need to reboot?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open `.profile` file using your desired editor:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Add this line to the file and save it:

```
export EDITOR=gedit
```

Logout and re-login. Now when you use `crontab -e` it would open `gedit`.

Remember that it's going to set `gedit` as default editors for other commands too, if you want it to only affect `crontab`, then you can create an alias:

```
alias crontab='EDITOR=gedit crontab'
```

Comment: For extra credit any idea why the other methods (mentioned above) didn't work?

Comment: Because  `crontab` opens the config files using editor defined in `EDITOR` variable... like most of the other commands.

Comment: You may want to use the ubuntu/debian program sensible-editor, which chooses a graphical / terminal text editor configured in /etc/alternatives depending on if you are in a X11 session or not.

Comment: I tried this procedure, but it doesn't work for me. crontab keeps opening in vim.